# What do the prefixes in the output of macOS pluginkit mean?

Tags: macos, plugins

Executing `pluginkit --match` in Terminal produces the following output (*unimportant lines skipped*):

```
+    com.apple.ncplugin.weather(1.0)
-    com.apple.share.SinaWeibo.post(1.0)
  H. com.apple.InternalFiltersXPC(2.0)
     com.apple.ncplugin.FindMyFriends(1.0)
!    com.mycompany.MyDemoPlugIn(1.0)
```

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33108757/1418981) with answer about `+` and `-` prefixes.

```
+ com.mycompany.finderExt(1) - If the extension is enabled
- com.mycompany.finderExt(1) - If the extension is not enabled
```

But what do the exclamation mark `!` and `H.` mean? What does it mean when there is no prefix at all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`!` means the Finder Sync extension is not running from the containing app. This is possible if you have multiple copies of the containing app on your system.

You can check extension path using this command:

```sh
/usr/bin/pluginkit -m -v -i com.mycompany.finderExt
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for this information? I am experiencing the same problem as the author. However I have the extension and its container app only once (in derived data by Xcode) which contradicts this answer.

Comment: I don't have any reference, this was observed on my system. You can check the path of finder extension in activity monitor.

Comment: That also does not fit together: I do not even have it in Activity Monitor. I opened [a dedicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66546696/769502) on how to debug this issue.

Comment: maybe something changed. Its 5 years old observation. Add/update your solution here.

Answer (score 0):

From the output of `man pluginkit`, under the `-m` command-line option:

```
All matching plug-ins are returned, one per line. Each line may begin with any one of the following tags indicating the user election state:

      + indicates that the user has elected to use the plug-in

      - indicates that the user has elected to ignore the plug-in

      ! indicates that the user has elected to use the plug-in for debugger use

      = indicates that the plug-in is superseded by another plug-in

      ? unknown user election state
```