# macOS Notification Service Extension not being used

Tags: macos, notifications, unnotificationserviceextension

I have a notification service extension for my macOS app.

Here is the code for that extension:

```
import UserNotifications

class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        print("Extension received notification!")

        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        bestAttemptContent?.title = "Title modified!"
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }
}
```

My payload is also pretty simple:

```
{"aps": {
        "alert":{"title":"Test1", "subtitle":"Test2", "body":"Test3"},
        "sound":"default",
        "mutable-content":1,
        "category":"news"
    }
}
```

However, upon receiving the notification, the title is not modified. I also tried the `Attach to process by PID or name` menu, I can not attach to this extension, which means it is not being ran.

Many other question were asking about iOS, I tried the solutions for those, but unfortunately they don't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You working with a Catalyst app/MacOS Catalina?

Comment: Use reverse domain notation for identifiers. On the Mac it’s pretty much required, otherwise you get strange behavior

Comment: Did you find any solutions. I can't get Notification Service working neither. I am developing a cocoa app with macOS 10.15.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for debugging the catalyst version?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you don't have multiple versions of the app installed.
After I deleted the release version of the app (same bundle ID), it all started to work.

*pluginkit* and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898903/what-do-the-prefixes-in-the-output-of-macos-pluginkit-mean) pushed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1- An other possibility to not have an app extension run (or seems like it was not run) is that some thing happened and the extension did fail/crash and the OS delivered the Push notification without changes. (try to debug your extension using Xcode.)

2- Try also clean your target and derived data in Xcode.

3- Ensure that your extensions' entitlement has all supported Mac (Mac Catalyst) and not only suported iOS keys (if using for Mac Catalyst).

4- (Mac Catalyst) Try to run the extension on iOS (if it did but not on the Mac it means that some configuration/code crash should not be in your Mac target) Again debugging should help

Comment: Cleaning build folder worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your notification target is supported mac? I had this trouble

[image: Notification settings]

Looks like notification dosn't run and your push notifications handled by system as is.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with ***Mac Catalyst*** (the iOS Notification Services extension is working fine but Not for MAC OS). (***Xcode 11.1***)
For Mac OS X (Mac Catalyst) (if you already have the "App Sandbox" capability please skip to step 5)

1. Select your extension's target.
2. then on top select the tab "***Signing and Capabilities***"
3. than click on Capability +
4. Add the "**App Sandbox**" *capability*
5. Ensure that **Incoming Connection (Server)** is checked (*enabled*).

Please see attached image. 
[Xcode Notification Services Extension target setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgZKI.png)

Comment: Point 5 is wrong and will get your app rejected. Incoming Connection is not required for push notifications and notification service extension to work.