# How to retrieve the XPC service of a file provider extension on macOS?

Tags: macos, xpc, fileprovider, fileprovider-extension, macos-app-extension

I have extended [my example project](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/macosfileproviderexample/tree/xpc) from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66546696/769502) with [an attempt to establish an XPC connection](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/macosfileproviderexample/commit/6a7df717b39c8b0eafbc53a5b747372dc71a5562).

In a different project we have successfully implemented the file provider for iOS. The exposed service must be resolved by URLs it is responsible for. On iOS it is the only possibility and on macOS it appears like that, too. Because on macOS the system takes care of managing files there are no URLs except the one which can be resolved through `NSFileProviderItemIdentifier.rootContainer`.

In [the `AppDelegate.didFinishLaunching()` method](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/macosfileproviderexample/blob/6a7df717b39c8b0eafbc53a5b747372dc71a5562/SomeProduct/AppDelegate.swift#L30) I try to retrieve the service like this (see linked code for full reference, I do not want to unnecessarily bloat this question page for now):

```swift
let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let fileProviderManager = NSFileProviderManager(for: domain)!
        
        fileProviderManager.getUserVisibleURL(for: NSFileProviderItemIdentifier.rootContainer) { url, error in
            // [...]

            fileManager.getFileProviderServicesForItem(at: url) { list, error in
                // list always contains 0 items!
            }
        }
```

The delivered list always is empty. However [the extension is creating a service source on initialization](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/macosfileproviderexample/blob/6a7df717b39c8b0eafbc53a5b747372dc71a5562/SomeProvider/FileProviderExtension.swift#L17) which creates an `NSXPCListener` which has [an `NSXPCListenerDelegate` that exports the `NSFileProviderReplicatedExtension` object on new connections](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/macosfileproviderexample/blob/6a7df717b39c8b0eafbc53a5b747372dc71a5562/SomeProvider/XPCListenerDelegate.swift). What am I missing?

```swift
func listener(_ listener: NSXPCListener, shouldAcceptNewConnection newConnection: NSXPCConnection) -> Bool {
        os_log("XPC listener delegate should accept new connection...")

        newConnection.exportedObject = fileProviderExtension
        newConnection.exportedInterface = NSXPCInterface(with: SomeProviderServiceInterface.self)
        newConnection.remoteObjectInterface = NSXPCInterface(with: SomeProductServiceInterface.self)
        newConnection.resume()

        return true
    }
```

Suspicious: [`serviceName` of the `FileProviderServiceSource` never is queried](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/macosfileproviderexample/blob/6a7df717b39c8b0eafbc53a5b747372dc71a5562/SomeProvider/FileProviderServiceSource.swift#L24). We are out of ideas why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a protocol which your extension's principal class can implement, NSFileProviderServicing.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider/nsfileproviderservicing

Comment: Thank you, this was the missing piece and difference in comparison to iOS. I updated [my example project](https://github.com/peterthomashorn/macosfileproviderexample/tree/xpc) accordingly.